# Ruby on Rails : Unable to install sqlite3 1.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite3-ruby

ruby : ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]

rails : 3.0.0

My Rails application needs sqlite 1.3.5. "Rails -v" says to run "bundle update sqlite3" but when I run the command, it says:

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Then I tried running "gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'" but it says:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

statement.c : ./sqlite3_ruby.h:16:34: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)

statement.c : error: ‘SIZEOF_BDIGITS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SIZEOF_INT’?

make: *** [Makefile:245: statement.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2